# extract records from a huge file, using a text pattern, with sed, awk, or perl

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have a huge file, which has each record separated by a blank line. I need to extract only those records, that contain a particular string in them. How would you approach this, should I use sed, awk, perl?

Example of input:

```
firstrecord
data
moredata

secondrecord
data
moredata2

...
```

I need to extract all records containing `moredata2`, so output would be

```
secondrecord
data
moredata2
```

perl code i have tried, but extracts each record to a new file,

how i could extract all records at once, and how could the patterns, be read from a file?

```
perl -00ne 's#PAT.*/(.*)\n##; open($F,">","$1.txt"); s/\n\s*(\n|$)//g; 
        print $F "$_\n"' original.txt
```

Comment: So what did you try for yourself? and how did you fail? Please post your own research efforts

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`awk` does magic in this case

```
awk -v RS= '/moredata2/{print (f?"\n":"")$0; f=1}' original.txt
```

you get,

```
secondrecord
data
moredata2

...
```

Comment: how would you alter this, so as to be able to read the moredata2 like values, from a txt file, and output in a separate file each time we find a new pattern?

Comment: `while read -r p; do awk -v RS= -v pattern="$p" '$0 ~ pattern{print (f?"\n":"")$0; f=1}' input_file.txt > "$p.output"; done < patterns.txt` something like this

Answer (score 2):

My answer would be - use perl, set `$/` and regex match your desired records.

`$/` is the record separator. Setting it to an empty string sets in to 'paragraph' mode, and thus iterates looking for blank lines. Which is exactly what you need.

`m/moredata2/` is implicitly matching the current block.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = '';

while ( <DATA> ) { 
    if ( m/moredata2/ ) { 
        print "Matched:\n";
        print;
    }
}

__DATA__
firstrecord
data
moredata

secondrecord
data
moredata2
```

Comment: how would you read DATA, from an external file? and how would you read also moredata2 and more patterns, again from an external file?

Comment: That's not the question you asked. But reading from a file is as simple as `open` and then using that file handle in the `while` loop instead of `DATA`. Reading patterns from another file... is also a question of `open`, read it, and compile up a regular expression that matches appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code may be helpful you on this one. And you can try to simplify as much as possible.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $joinline = do { local $/; <DATA> }; 
while($joinline=~m/\n{2}((?:(?!moredata2).)*)moredata2\n/gs)
{
    print "Matched: $&\n";
}


__DATA__
firstrecord
data
moredata

secondrecord
data
moredata2

thirdrecord
data
moredata

fourthrecord
data
moredata2
```

Thanks.

Comment: What, so... you're setting the record separator, but then iterating the whole file concatenating it? And then regex matching? That's a pretty ugly way of writing `my $joinline = do { local $/; <DATA> };`

Comment: That's why in my answer `And you can try to simplify as much as possible.`

Answer (score 0):

An `awk`:

```
awk '/moredata2/' RS="" yourfile
```

**Explanation**

> Another technique is to have blank lines separate records. By a
>   special dispensation, an empty string as the value of RS indicates
>   that records are separated by one or more blank lines. **When RS is set
>   to the empty string, each record always ends at the first blank line
>   encountered. The next record doesn’t start until the first nonblank
>   line that follows**. No matter how many blank lines appear in a row,
>   they all act as one record separator. (Blank lines must be completely
>   empty; lines that contain only whitespace do not count.)

Check the [`docs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html)